# Gibt es ein Wort, das 'etwas' und 'jemand' zusammenfasst?

Tags: single-word-request

`etwas` bezieht sich nur auf Dinge (und Tiere?), `jemand` nur auf
Personen. Gibt es ein Wort, das beide Sachen bedeuten kann?

Hintergrund: Ich übersetze gerade ein paar prädikatenlogische Klauseln
in Deutsch. Wenn man ein `x` hat, dass überhaupt nicht über ein
Prädikat genauer definiert wird, z.B.

```
∃x schön(x)
```

wie umschreibt man dann `x`?

```
Etwas ist schön.
Jemand ist schön.
Etwas/jemand ist schön.
```

Und sind bei dieser Umschreibung Tiere auch dabei?

Comment: Wäre die Frage evtl. bei linguistics.SE besser aufgehoben?

Comment: *Etwas* umfasst durchaus Tiere. Du sagst doch zum Beispiel: *Ich glaub, mich hat etwas gestochen.* und meinst damit ja - i.d.R. - eine Mücke oder Milbe, evnt. auch Zecken oder Wespen. Wenn du Tiere und Menschen unter einen Hut bringen möchtest, passt natürlich *Lebewesen* am besten, vorausgesetzt du beziehst dich nur auf Lebende. Die Kombination mit Gegenständen wird schwierieger und dir bleiben wohl nur die bereits genannten Begriffe Entität und Objekt. Zumindest wüsste ich auch nichts mehr. ... to be continued...

Comment: cont'd ... Naja, zumindest gibt es noch eine Möglichkeit, wie du den Mensch auch unter *etwas* zusammenfassen kannst. Wenn du ihn nicht mehr in der Gesamtheit betrachtest, sondern z.b. auf Körperteile reduzieren würdest. Dann redest du von Gesicht, Körper, Muskeln, Haut, whatever. Und dann passt *etwas* wieder. Aber ich glaube, genau das willst du eben nicht. Und da - imho - gibt echt keine besseren Wörter, als die von Hauser vorgeschlagenen.

Comment: Um Mensch u. Tier unter einen Hut zu bringen reicht - außer man ist religiös - das Tier. `Lebewesen` wäre sinnig, wenn man unter den Pflanzenhut wollte, oder mit Pilzen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bei Prädikatenlogik denk ich an Philosophie und Ontologie, dann fällt mir z.B.

> Entität, Objekt

als neutraler Sammelbegriff ein. Klingt natürlich geschwollen, wenn du *jemand* meinst und *Entität* verwendest (weil jemand/etwas eben sehr gebräuchlich ist). Objekt wie in *Objekt der Begierde* (bei der jemand nicht etwas gemeint ist) scheint da schon gebräuchlicher. Aber klingt auch irgendwie nach *Ding* und damit abwertend. Aber bei Tierversuchen oder psychologischen Versuchen spricht man auch von *Versuchsobjekt*. Scheint mir benutzbar in deinem Zusammenhang. Ob das gebräuchlicher besser ist als beim *etwas/jemand* zu bleiben in deinem genauen Zusammenhang und Bereich?

Comment: Entität finde ich gut... das benutze ich im Sprachunterricht auch immer, um ein unbestimmtes Objekt zu benennen ohne Objekt zu sagen... objekt klingt halt nach Sache, wie du schon sagst

Comment: Zu dem Beispiel "Etwas/jemand ist schön." passt "Subjekt" besser, oder?